# Dependent objects not being created

Tags: factory-bot

I have a Sale and dependent SaleItem classes

```
class Sale
    has_many :sale_items
end

class SaleItem
    belongs_to :sale
end
```

I have a Factories for both of these...

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :sale_item do
        sale
    end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :sale do
        sequence(:name) {|n| "Name #{n}" }

        factory :sale_with_sale_items do
            after :build do |sale|
                build_list :sale_item, 5, :sale => sale
            end
        end
    end
end
```

I then create the object from a test function as...

```
object = create :sale_with_sale_items
assert object.save, 'Error saving sale'
```

Despite following the original document closely I still get...

```
Minitest::UnexpectedError: ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Sale must have at least one sale item.
    test/models/sale_test.rb:14:in `block in <class:SaleTest>'
test/models/sale_test.rb:14:in `block in <class:SaleTest>'
```

Any ideas on where this could be going wrong?

Comment: Maybe the `build_list` doesn't get saved with the `#save` call on `:sale_with_sale_items`. In your `after :build` callback, I would try something like `sale.sale_items << create_list :sale_item, 5`

Comment: FactoryGirl mandates the use attribute value pairs (without the <<) so I tried doing `sale.sale_items build_list :sale_item, 5` (and `create_list`) but still get the same error `Sale must have at least one sale item` from our validation checking each time.

Comment: Found a solution - it was to assign the sale_items during the construction of the object i.e. `sale_items { build_list :sale_item, 5 }`.